# Handle Autentication/Authorization for static file requests in Node

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, express

I've implemented authentication & authorization within a node.js application on every rest call.

```
app.post('/api/users/:userId', requiresAuthentication, authorization.auth.can('find user'), user.findOne);
```

With this I make sure that only authorized users can execute this rest call.

How can I implement this for static rest calls like

```
 /img/{userId}/some_image.png
```

I tried:

```
app.get('/img/:userId/some_image.png',requiresAuthentication, authorization.auth.can('find user'))
```

but since I didn't do anything else I'm not surprised that this didn't work.What would be the correct way to implement Authentication & Authorization for static files?

*edit* server.js express config:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 86400000 }));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views/');
```

Comment: What do you use to serve the static files?

Comment: I just edited the express config for my static files

Comment: and, does the code that adds the auth come before, or after the static middleware. If it comes after, that would explain why it is ignored.

Comment: first is the express config from above and after that are my routes. Should my approach of manually add routes like `app.get('/api/:userId....')` work since I dont actually have a method to call like with "normal" rest calls?

Comment: I'm kinda curious if you could simply add your `requiresAuthentication, authorization.auth.can('find user')` directly to your static middleware .use call. it would have to come first.

Comment: technically I could do `app.use(requiresAuthentication, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 86400000 }));` but then I can't send any request after the server restart since I don't have my token in the session yet and the request to `/` fails